# How to Sort/Ordering of array list of array that start with the charecter not numeric in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an Array :

```
data =["c3.2xlarge","c3.4xlarge","c3.large"];

data= [ "c3.4xLarge", "c3.2xLarge", "c3.8xLarge", "c3.Large",
        "d3.4xLarge", "d3.2xLarge", "d3.8xLarge", "d3.Large", 
        "t2.4xLarge", "t2.2xLarge", "t2.8xLarge", "t2.Large"
      ];
```

it's alphabetical now and sorted, but that gives us  when we really want `c3.large` to appear first.

**Expecting output** = ["c3.Large","c3.2xLarge","c3.4xLarge", "c3.8xLarge",
                     "d3.Large","d3.2xLarge", "d3.4xLarge", "d3.8xLarge",
                      "t2.Large","t2.2xLarge", "t2.4xLarge", "t2.8xLarge" 
                     ];

How do I create a function to sort the objects like this?

Comment: How do you want them sorted, what output do you expect?

Comment: hi and welcome, please provide your code attempts so far so that we can help. People are rarely inclined to code for you without evidence of effort.

as David said, also include expecting output.

Comment: data= [ "c3.4xLarge", "c3.2xLarge", "c3.8xLarge", "c3.Large", "d3.4xLarge", "d3.2xLarge", "d3.8xLarge", "d3.Large", "t2.4xLarge", "t2.2xLarge", "t2.8xLarge", "t2.Large", ]; 

expecting output : ["c3.Large","c3.2xLarge","c3.4xLarge", "c3.8xLarge", "d3.Large","d3.2xLarge", "d3.4xLarge", "d3.8xLarge", "t2.Large","t2.2xLarge", "t2.4xLarge", "t2.8xLarge" ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite the js array sort method;
hope this might help

```js
var data = ["c3.2xlarge","c3.4xlarge","c3.large"];
    console.log(data.sort(function (a,b) {
        var aSub = a.substring(3,4),
        bSub = b.substring(3,4);
    if(isNaN(aSub)){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(isNaN(bSub)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return aSub > bSub ? 1:-1;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Curtis , Work fine .
But, I have Array Like , 
data= [
"c3.4xLarge", "c3.2xLarge", "c3.8xLarge", "c3.Large",
"d3.4xLarge", "d3.2xLarge", "d3.8xLarge", "d3.Large",
"t2.4xLarge", "t2.2xLarge", "t2.8xLarge", "t2.Large",
];

expecting output : 
["c3.Large","c3.2xLarge","c3.4xLarge", "c3.8xLarge",
 "d3.Large","d3.2xLarge", "d3.4xLarge", "d3.8xLarge",
 "t2.Large","t2.2xLarge", "t2.4xLarge", "t2.8xLarge",
];

At that time it's  fail.

Comment: that means you should check the first character before check the fourth character

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = [ "c3.4xLarge", "c3.2xLarge", "c3.8xLarge", "c3.Large", "d3.4xLarge", "d3.2xLarge", "d3.8xLarge", "d3.Large", "t2.4xLarge", "t2.2xLarge", "t2.8xLarge", "t2.Large", ];


 data.sort(function (a,b) {
    var firA = a.substring(0,1),
        firB = b.substring(0,1);
        // console.log(firA);
        // console.log(firB);
    if(firA != firB){
        return firA >firB ? 1 : -1;
    }
    var aSub = a.substring(3,4),
    bSub = b.substring(3,4);
    if(isNaN(aSub)){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(isNaN(bSub)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return aSub > bSub ? 1:-1;
    }
})
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: Done.. Excellent . Work fine. Thanks Chen.

Comment: Just few changes in Input Array...
i have this type of array format :
data=[
Object { key="c3.2xlarge",  id=85},
Object { key="c3.4xlarge",  id=86},
Object { key="c3.8xlarge",  id=88},
Object { key="c3.large",  id=83}, 
Object { key="c3.xlarge",  id=84},
Object { key="c4.2xlarge",  id=89},
Object { key="c4.4xlarge",  id=91},
Object { key="c4.8xlarge",  id=92},
Object { key="c4.large",  id=87},
Object { key="c4.xlarge",  id=90},
Object { key="d2.2xlarge",  id=104},
Object { key="d2.4xlarge",  id=103},
Object { key="d2.8xlarge",  id=105},
Object { key="d2.xlarge",  id=102}];

Comment: I m trying like this : use a1.key,But output not comes properly.

 data.sort(function (a1, b1) {
            var a = a1.key;
            var b = b1.key;
             -------
             -------
             --------
           return data;
}

Comment: change the return value to 1 or -1 or 0